# Error on __construct when called class

Tags: php

i have class on PHP, and when called it the function `__construct($_POST)` must be process.

the `__construct()` function define as :

```
// Constructor Function
function __construct($_POST){
    $this->customer       = trim($_POST['customer']);
    $this->CreateDate   = date('Y/m/d');    
}
```

when i called any function on class, its processed and insert to DataBase but this massage is appear :-

```
Missing argument 1 for Draft::__construct(), called in ....
```

what wrong on my code

thankx

Comment: How are you instantiating your object?

Comment: how do you start the class? And why passing $_POST through in you constructor? `function __construct(){` instead of  `function __construct($_POST){` will probbly solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP also should throw a notice when you try to use reserved variables, like, `$_POST`, `$_GET`and `$_COOKIE` with "Illegal offset".

From your question, seems like you do not understand [the difference between function parameters and arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29). You're already passing an argument, while it should be a parameter.

This:

```
function __construct($_POST){
    $this->customer       = trim($_POST['customer']);
    $this->CreateDate   = date('Y/m/d');    
}
```

Should be rewritten as:

```
function __construct($POST){
    $this->customer       = trim($POST['customer']);
    $this->CreateDate   = date('Y/m/d');    
}
```

And then:

```
$object = new YourClass($_POST);
```

Answer (score 3):

I am confused as to your intent.

`$_POST` is a [PHP superglobal](http://www.php.net/manualyou/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), meaning that it is available in all scopes.

**If your intent is to use posted data:**

There is no need to pass it as an argument

**If you are passing a variable that you just so happen to call $_POST:**

Change the name of the variable.

Comment: As a third possibility: If you are trying to use posted data most of the time, but allow another array in future, use something like `function __construct($input_data) { ... }` and *call* it with `new Draft($_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong:

1. Your class constructor takes a super global as an argument.
2. You probably don't pass an argument to the call to construct an object:

For number 2, you should be calling:

`$draft = new Draft($var);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_post is super global variable and you are using as constructor parameter change the variable name 
function __construct($post){

    $this->customer       = trim($post['customer']);
    $this->CreateDate   = date('Y/m/d');    
}

Or Second remove $_Post in constructor parameter 

function __construct(){

        $this->customer       = trim($_POST['customer']);
        $this->CreateDate   = date('Y/m/d');    
    }
```